# What is the Rationale Behind Different Log File Sizes Used in HDFS

Tags: logging, hadoop, hdfs

I'm currently working on implementing a logging system for a new Hadoop cluster I've setup. The way I've always seen these setup in the past was logging split off by days with individual files split off at around 10x HDFS block size. I haven't had any problems with this methodology when I've needed to use it, but after a discussion with a coworker who wanted to store logs in one long file, I realized I wasn't really sure why the 10x methodology I mentioned was used. The reasons I could think of are:

1. mapreduce jobs will run significantly faster when we're only interested in a couple of days.
2. files can be zipped/tar'd/lzo'd up to save space.

Are there others? I couldn't really figure out why people shard files for a single day by the 10x HDFS block size level. I figure for my knowledge of theory it would be very cool to know more about the philosophy of why logs are stored at different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigger your files, the better job the JobTracker will do scheduling your jobs.  Super small files will mean lots of tasks, which will create bad performance.  However, having mega huge files doesn't let you query just parts of your dataset.  You need to find a balance between how much data you're producing per day, and how big your files will be.  If you can produce 10x the block size per day, then have a file per day -- that way it'll be easy for you to query only 5 days worth.  Otherwise, consider creating an ETL job to concat files together.

Comment: That makes sense. So then there's no good reason to divide files within a day at all? The way I've seen this done in the past is that log files would be cut off at sizes of 720mb, or something near there, even within a single day (so, for example, if a day had 7gb of logs, they would be logged as 9 files of 720mb and 1 file of slightly less than 720mb). I can understand dividing by day, but not dividing smaller than that.